# uncaught referenceError :angular is not defined (anonymous function)

Tags: angularjs

i am trying to implement searching concept using filter Filter, I'm getting this error and I'm unable to sort this error even I've gone through so many articles and solutions, none suites best for this ... please help !!!!
here is the code.....>

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
#span1{
border:2px dashed blue;
background-color:lime;
padding:0px;
margin-left:5px;
}
hr{
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
background-color:red;
height:5px;
}   
h1{
border:2px solid lime;
background-color:orange;;
color:yellow;
padding:0px;
margin:0px;
position:relative;
width:100%;
float:left;
}
h1:first-line 
{
    color:green

}
</style>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" >
<h1><span id="span1">5-11-2016</span> ... Angular JS Filters implemented in Searching.</h1><br><br>
<hr>
<div ng-controller="myAppController">
Student Name : <input ng-model="searchobj.sname"/>
<br>
Select course : <select ng-model="searchobj.course">
                    <option>angular js</option>
                    <option>html</option>
                    <option>css</option>
                    <option>java script</option>
                    <option>jQuery</option>
                    <option>Bootstrap</option>
                </select>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<table border="2">
    <tr>
        <th>Student Name</th>
        <th>Course</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in students | filter : searchobj">
        <td>{{item.sname}}</td>
        <td>{{item.course}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</div>

<script scr="angular.js"></script>
<script>
var app=angular.module("myApp",[]);
app.controller("myAppController",
        function($scope){

                $scope.searchobj={sname:" ",course:" "};
                $scope.students=[
                    {sname:"scott",course:"html"},
                    {sname:"rock",course:"css"},
                    {sname:"umar",course:"jQuery"},
                    {sname:"asad",course:"angular js"},
                    {sname:"nayeem",course:"html"},
                    {sname:"onida",course:"html"},
                    {sname:"shakes",course:"java script"},
                    {sname:"rony",course:"html"},
                    {sname:"rock",course:"Html"},
                    {sname:"asif",course:"css"},
                    {sname:"onida",course:"java script"},
                    {sname:"sammy",course:"Html"},
                    {sname:"huber",course:"angular js"},
                    {sname:"watson",course:"Html"},
                    {sname:"azzy",course:"Html"},
                    {sname:"katy",course:"bootstrap"},
                    {sname:"randy",course:"css"},
                    {sname:"sammy",course:"html"},
                    {sname:"jaab",course:"angular js"},
                    {sname:"randy",course:"html"},
                    {sname:"peter",course:"css"}];
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is your script `angular.js` ?

Comment: its in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

Change `<script scr="angular.js"></script>` to `<script src="angular.js"></script>`
**Change========^ -----------------------------------------------------^**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="angular.js"></script>
```

Comment: my dear frnd <script> can be added in <body> and <head> .i've given you the complete code just try it in notepad++ and debug it in chrome . press f12 in chrome you can see the error.